# Trigger Functions - Make a trigger that sets the column "inicijali" whenever something is added or changed in table "zaposlenici"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

[LINK TO PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/0t9BSs0Z)

**Questions**:

**1)**

-- add a column "inicijali" (type VARCHAR ) to the table "zaposlenici"

-- make a trigger that sets the column "inicijali" (fills it with initials from names of people in table "zaposlenici")

--whenever something is inserted or updated in table "zaposlenici"

**2)**

**This question has been resolved**

--make a trigger that sets the column "cijena_ukupno" whenever there is changed or added row in table "proizvodi"

--Set is cijena_ukupno = cijena_bez_pdv + pdv_vrijednost

[LINK TO PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/0t9BSs0Z)

This is answer to quesiton 2). I need help with question 1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_proizvod
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON proizvodi
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.cijena_bez_pdv := :NEW.cijena_ukupno - :NEW.pdv;
END;
```

Comment: Is there a question here? If so, it's not clear. Can you [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking? And while  you're at it, can you edit your question title to something meaningful? *SQLDeveloper* is redundant, as it's already available from the tags, and *student help* is pretty much meaningless. Your title should describe your question or problem clearly enough that a future user of this site gets information from it when scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem, and your current title doesn't do that at all. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite , I'm new to the editing here, I have edited my title. Hope it is good now ^^

Comment: Questions are:
1)
-- add a column "inicijali"  (type VARCHAR )to the table "zaposlenici"
--make a trigger that sets the column "inicijali" (fills it with initials) whenever something is added or changed in table "zaposlenici"

2)
--make a trigger that sets the column "cijena_ukupno" whenever there is changed or added row in table "proizvodi"
--Set is cijena_ukupno = cijena_bez_pdv + pdv_vrijednost

Comment: Please edit/improve the question! (1) Please translate all words/identifiers to English (you can translate them back at your place when you've been helped...). (2) Please take care of the question formatting. (3) Please avoid any "noise" (words about corona, your private situation, adding contact addresses for other channels/platforms), which are deprecated/forbidden alltogether.

Comment: @HelpingHand thanks for info, I removed "noise", amm some of those are names of the tables from the code that are not translateble but I will translate the rest of it

Comment: @Mooncake - Then consider to reduce the pastebin stuff to a *minimal example* you can post inline within the question. There, it shouldn't be a problem to translate the remaining few non-English terms.

Comment: I did reduce it to minimal stuff to translate, only table names are not translated in paste bin ^^ But the table names are re-used over a 100 times, i don't think the name of the table should be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a *shorter* version of your table as the rest is irrelevant for this case.

```
SQL> create table zaposlenici (
  2    id      number not null,
  3    ime     varchar2(20 char) not null,
  4    prezime varchar2(20 char) not null
  5  );

Table created.
```

Add a new column:

```
SQL> alter table zaposlenici add inicijali varchar2(5);

Table altered.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_aiu_zap
  2    before insert or update on zaposlenici
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.inicijali := upper(substr(:new.ime, 1, 1)) ||
  6                      upper(substr(:new.prezime, 1, 1));
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into zaposlenici (id, ime, prezime) values (1, 'Little', 'Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into zaposlenici (id, ime, prezime) values (2, 'Velika', 'Gorica');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From zaposlenici order by id;

        ID IME                  PREZIME              INICI
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -----
         1 Little               Foot                 LF
         2 Velika               Gorica               VG

SQL> update zaposlenici set prezime = 'Zagreb' where id = 2;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From zaposlenici order by id;

        ID IME                  PREZIME              INICI
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -----
         1 Little               Foot                 LF
         2 Velika               Zagreb               VZ

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answers**:

1) Still needed

2)

```
create or replace trigger t_proizvod
before insert or update proizvodi
for each row
begin
:NEW.cijena_bez_pdv := :NEW.cijena_ukupno - :NEW.pdv;
end;
```

Comment: Has your capslock key got stuck? Please re-format the answer.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry we on collage for some reason must use caps lock on commands

Comment: This is a public website, not your college. Please use normal spelling (and rewrite what you take back to your class). On any kinds of usenet, using capital-only spelling is read like hearing somebody shout and yell, which is at best perceived as impolite. An exception in software-related Q&A is any identifier that must be capitalized in the corresponding language, and certain typing conventions as, e.g., writing constants in C and similar languages in capitals.

Comment: Oracle's typing conventions also support capitalization for most of the keywords, and  there's no problem with the previous edit @HelpingHand .

Comment: ^This, I see 99% ppl use caps but no reason to argue, if he wants it in no caps its not problem for me to do it, Peace.